# Displaying SVG maps in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, svg, vector

I am working on an iOS app where my requirement is to render the **SVG maps** , zoom and highlight the selected state.

I am using the following code to display it:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"svg"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

I am able to zoom it using the above code, but my problem is I want to highlight the selected portion. For Example, in India map I want to select one state and highlight that.

Also, I have read about [SVGKIT](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit). Is it possible to get the above functionality using this library? Or if you have any other way then please suggest.